# I can't unmask a service on Kubuntu Wily 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, services, systemd, cryptsetup

I'm using Kubuntu Wily 15.10 (fully upgraded). It already had installed the `cryptsetup` package.

I'm trying to start the cryptdisks service but I get this:

```
$ sudo service cryptdisks start
Failed to start cryptdisks.service: Unit cryptdisks.service is masked.
```

And yes, it's masked.

```
$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep cryptdisks
cryptdisks-early.service                   masked  
cryptdisks.service                         masked
```

If I try to unmask the service, nothing happens.

```
$ sudo systemctl unmask cryptdisks-early.service 
$ sudo systemctl unmask cryptdisks.service 
$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep cryptdisks
cryptdisks-early.service                   masked  
cryptdisks.service                         masked
```

Take note that `systemctl unmask` does not return anything. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you have a symlink `/etc/systemd/system/cryptdisks.service` or `/lib/systemd/system/cryptdisks.service` to `/dev/null`. If so, delete the symlink manually.

And also for `cryptdisks-early.service`.

After that:

```
sudo apt-get remove cryptsetup
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup
```

Comment: I made some changes on your answer but it worked. It was necessary to reinstall `cryptsetup`. Thanks,

Comment: just as an update to this, running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure cryptsetup` after remove the symlinks is better practice. Just tested it working