# Cannot restart samba, samba.service is masked

Tags: samba

When I try to restart Samba, I am receiving the following error message:

```
Failed to start samba.service: Unit samba.service is masked.
```

In addition, when I run `systemctl`, it shows `smbd.service` in red showing failed.

At the same time restart began to fail, I have lost the share ability in folders created and cannot access.  Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 167):

Debian and debian-derivatives changed the service name from 'samba' to 'smbd'.

Try `service smbd restart`.

Comment: anyone know why?

Comment: @BenCreasy probably because the protocol's name is [`smb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block), and since this is a daemon, you get `smbd`.  [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)) is the name of one of the implementations of the `smb` protocol.

Comment: Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: @M-at That generally means there's an error in your config file.  The things it is suggesting you look at will spell that out further.

Answer (score 48):

Try:

```
sudo systemctl unmask samba
sudo systemctl enable samba
sudo systemctl restart samba
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303293/ubuntu-service-samba-is-masked-and-cant-start

Comment: This worked for me with a similar problem with mongodb on Ubuntu 16 after upgrading from 14.  I changed the first line, though, to systemctl unmask mongodb.service.  After doing this, service mongodb status/start/stop works.

Comment: Failed to restart samba.service: Unit samba.service is masked.

Comment: This seemed to work at first: smbd restarted properly, no logs or errors, but it was still impossible to connect to samba from another machine. The only thing that worked at the end was to uninstall and reinstall samba

Comment: same problem as the guy above, only this one solved here

Comment: Thanks! This answer worked for me with php7.4-fpm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What is masking?  And should it be re-masked?

Answer (score 5):

This works for me(Ubuntu server 16):

```
sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/samba.service 
sudo systemctl enable samba.service nmbd.service
sudo systemctl start samba
```

Found it from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729897/i-cant-unmask-a-service-on-kubuntu-wily-15-10)

Comment: I had the same errors as the OP while running *Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS*. This solution fixed the issue for me.

Comment: ouch  ls -l /lib/systemd/system/samba.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar  5  2018 /lib/systemd/system/samba.service -> /dev/null

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem for no apparent reason. Checking the logs I saw that Samba had problems with cached files (improper permissions). `rm -R /var/cache/samba/*` did the trick.

Comment: Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.