# Unit packagekit.service is masked

Tags: services

When I update my system using `apt update` or try to install a new package with `aptitude` or `apt`, I receive this error :

```
Error : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked : Unit packagekit.service is masked.
```

I tried this [Cannot restart samba, samba.service is masked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754572/cannot-restart-samba-samba-service-is-masked). This does not fix my problem. I also researched but can't find anything about this problem.

When I run the commands:

```
 Unit unit.service does not exist, proceeding anyway.
```

I use Ubuntu Budgie 17.10 - 64 Bit.

Comment: "When I run the commands:" What does this mean? Which commands did you run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo systemctl unmask packagekit.service
sudo systemctl start packagekit.service
```

Then reboot.